# Cosmos DB hybrid data APIs access (MongoDB & Gremin)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Is it possible to add data with the MongoDB APIs, then add edges between the documents with Gremlin, and query the same data with both APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible today due to MongoDB's use of BSON which is not standard JSON. It is technically possible however to have SQL and Gremlin API within Cosmos DB.

Comment: Thanks Mark, any future plans to support it?